# Unable to install driver RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222

Tags: wireless

My kernel version: 5.4.0-42-generic.
Drivers that I got in CD: RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222

While installing [aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus: RealTek RTL8188eus WiFi driver with monitor mode & frame injection support](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus), I'm getting this error

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot create regular file '/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko': Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:2065: install] Error 1
```

The device is working fine on Windows. Is there any other driver package for this device?

Comment: It look like you are not using `sudo`.

Comment: Run `sudo make install` instead of `make install`.

Comment: Tried this also sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I installed this [aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus: RealTek RTL8188eus WiFi driver with monitor mode & frame injection support](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus) and then this [corneal64/Realtek-USB-Wireless-Adapter-Drivers: Realtek USB Wireless Adapter Drivers [0bda:f179] (Kernel 4.15.x ~ 5.9.x)](https://github.com/corneal64/Realtek-USB-Wireless-Adapter-Drivers). And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
cd rtl8188eus
make clean
git pull
sudo dkms-install.sh
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: thank you for helping me